# Backspace to beginning of line in IntelliJ

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, backspace

Pretty much everywhere in OSX, it's possible to backspace all the way to the beginning of a line using <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Backward delete</kbd>. I can't find a way to set up this behaviour within IntelliJ IDEA, and I find this very...

...backward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some basic keyboard shortcuts:

- Move Caret to Word Start: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.
- Move Caret to Line Start: <kbd>Home</kbd>
- Delete from Caret to Word Start: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>
- Delete from Caret to Line Start: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>

I assume you want to **Delete from Caret to Line Start** ("backspace to beginning of line").

If you want to execute this action with a single key, simply record a macro and assign a keyboard shortcut for it.

- Menu -> Macros -> Start Macro Recording
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Menu -> Macros -> Stop Macro Recording
- Assign a name, for example "Delete to Line Start"
- Assign a shortcut to your macro: Menu -> File -> Settings -> Keymap

Here's a screenshot of the settings dialog. I tested it and it works fine.
[image: Assign a shortcut to your macro]

Comment: I don't think he's asking about __moving__ the caret but rather deleting from caret position to line start. This is the default behavior in OS X.

Comment: Thanks, I am a Windows user and was not aware of this.

Comment: @benregn please review again; I modified my answer and now describe how "delete from caret position to line start" by recording a macro with two key strokes and execute it with a single key shortcut. Works fine!

Comment: Thanks, at least this works OK. Only problem is when you undo the text you deleted is selected (not a huge problem... yet ;P).